# Declare AngularJS1 directive to uppercase text into existent element

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I need to create a directive that uppercase all letter of content of a elem

```
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

with addition of all-uppercase

```
<div all-uppercase>HELLO WORLD!</div>
```

My mission is understending how Angular can provide an ability to manipulate text into existing html via "directive"

Please post working code...

Comment: you haven't asked a question, you have provided a problem statement and asked for the solution to be posted.  This isn't generally how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Sorry need problem refactoring!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this could have been easily done via CSS directly by just by saying css rule `text-transform: uppercase`.

Directive version would be, like below. Where you are accessing element text via `link` function, make it uppercase & put it back to the text of the element.

**Directive**

```
.directive('allUppercase', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
       element.text(element.text().toUpperCase());
    }
  }
});
```

Same thing can be achievable via using angular built in filter called as `uppercase`

```
{{ 'Hello World!'| uppercase }}
```

[**Demo Of All 3**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mFznZb385XkUCj9ZQNHl?p=preview)

Comment: CSS WoW! But it's only a case of stude to understending angular!

Comment: @cicciodarkast that's why I had all 3 possible way, so that you can understand well, Thanks :)

Comment: Pleased to help you, Thanks ;)